# Register form customer custom

Tags: customer, magento-1, register

i need to create a custom form for the registration customer.

i have used the file

```
/app/design/frontend/default/{theme}/template/customer/formregister.phtml
```

I entered:

```
<input  type="text" class="input-text " name="company" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>"  />
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " id="billing:vat_id" name="vat_id" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getVatId()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('VAT Number') ?>" class="input-text " />
```

but the value is not recorded.

Why?

Comment: What you mean by not recorded? Magento will not automatically save the fields you are adding to the forms. You need to make necessary changes like overriding controller action or adding customer attributes etc.

Comment: I have not to add new fields.
I inserted the old fields: vat_id, company in form page "create account"

Comment: oops! didn't check the field names.

Comment: The values for vat_id and company are not recording, correct?

Answer (score 0):

By Default, magento has the functioanlity to save the fields like `company` and `vat_id`. You don't need add them to the form, if you copied it from unmodified base template.

Go to **System >> Configuration >> Customer configuration >> Create new account options** and then update **Show VAT Number on Frontend** to *Yes*.

Don't forget to choose the appropriate website scope if you are on a multistore.

Flush magento cache once done.